# Check outlook send email

Tags: vbscript

I need help with my first VBS script. Basically I want to check if outlook is open, if not I want to open the program, if/when it is open I want to send an email.

```
 set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "outlook.exe"(
        goto "send"
        ) else (
         goto "Open"
         )
    End If
Open:
    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE""")
    Set objShell = Nothing
    GOTO send
send:
    wscript.Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        objMessage.Subject = "Sign in- please reply!"
        objMessage.Sender = "test@gmail.com"
        objMessage.From = "test@gmail.com"
        objMessage.To = "test@gmail.com"
        objMessage.TextBody = Test Body Email
        '==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.
        '==Normally you will only change the server name or IP.
        objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
        objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
        'Server port (typically 25)
        objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
        '==End remote SMTP server configuration section==
        objMessage.Send
        exit
```

I do know my email part works as I can run that and send my email. I'm having issues with the "If, ELSE, THEN" statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Process.Name = "outlook.exe" Then
    send
Else
    open    
End If
```

Will be the correct format for If..Then..Else, but vbscript does not support GoTo statements.  If you convert send and open to functions then you will be able to call them as shown above